# Getting current user in Liferay 6.2 (themeDisplay always null)

Tags: jsp, liferay, struts-1

I try to get the id of current user in jsp page usinge :

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.theme.*" %>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<liferay-theme:defineObjects />
<%
themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
User objUser=themeDisplay.getUser(); 
%>
```

but themeDisplay return always null !!

I have also tried to get it in my struts action using :

```
public class acces extends Action {
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws Exception {
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay =
(ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
Long currentuser = themeDisplay.getUserId();
```

but still return null

i'm using liferay 6.2 ce, webmodule struts 1.2 deployed into liferay as war file using install in appManager.

Please help, i'm missing some configurations?

Comment: What do you refer speaking of "webmodule struts"? Official struts portlet bridge, or Liferay Struts portlet bridge?

Comment: "webmodule struts" refer a webapplication developped with struts framework, not a portlet. I have djust deployed it into liferay portal using App Manager install function without changing. The app is déployed and i can add it into a liferay page.But i want to get the current user from Liferay to add some controls. The problem is : the HttpServletRequest request doesn't contain the WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY, it return null. can u help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following by your reply to my initial question...

If your Struts application can be added, it means that it has at least a portlet.xml file inside (I don't know if Liferay Application Manager add it for you)... in any case you can't access to context in this way.

The best way to create a portlet application by Struts, is using [Struts Portlet Bridge](http://portals.apache.org/bridges/bridges-struts/) ; how you can see in the link I provided it allows to your code to become compliant with JSR specifications; then it should be able to rigth interact with portlet container...

You can just try with one action and test if it solves your problem... the conversion between standard web application to portlet application should be as painless as possible.

Comment: Thank You Cira, i've finally deploy deployed my struts appli into liferay using Struts Portlet Bridge and now i can get the themeDisplay. but i have an other problem in my jsp files using tag librairies like : <logic:redirect action="acces.do"></logic:redirect> error : org.apache.struts.config.impl.ModuleConfigImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.struts.config.ModuleConfig

Comment: This sounds new to me... can you verify if there are different versions for your struts libraries? PS. If my original answer to your problem is working, a "mark as solution" would be nice... :)

Comment: Hi Cira, in WEB_INF/lib of my appli i've :portals-bridges,portals-bridges-common-1.0.4,portals-bridges-struts-1.2.7-1.0.4,struts-1.2.7,struts-el-1.2.7, util-bridges, util-java, util-taglib and others like itext,jdom,... i've this error on index.jsp file org.apache.struts.config.impl.ModuleConfigImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.struts.config.ModuleConfig                                                    java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: my index.jsp file :                                                                 <%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://portals.apache.org/bridges/struts/tags-portlet-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://portals.apache.org/bridges/struts/tags-portlet-html-el" prefix="html-el" %>
<%@ include file="/init.jsp" %>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<logic:redirect action="acces.do"></logic:redirect>

Comment: I suppose your problem doesn't be in your jsp file, but in your libraries configuration... for investigation purposes, did you try to empty your JSP file and to add one by one pieces of code to verify what brakes your execution? You can do the same by deleting your lib/struts-*  and inserting only required jars when ClassNotFoundExceptions occour. I know this is boring, but can be a good way to investigate...

Comment: PS: make sure you are using Apache struts bridge (so jars containing org.apache.* packages) and not Liferay Struts Bridge (with com.liferay.* packages).

Comment: Hi Cira, after investigation i found that the problem is when using tags containing actions like : <logic:redirect action="/acces" forward=""></logic:redirect> or <html:link action="/acces"></html:link> but if i use a tag without action i've no problem like :<html:button property="click" onclick="alert();"></html:button>, i think the problem is that he's not viewing the action. in my struts-config.xml i've the action declared :<action path="/acces" type="Alg.Bull.Portal.acces">, certainely i'm missing some configuration detail

Comment: when i replace <logic:redirect  by <form action="/acces" ... i've this error The requested resource was not found. http://localhost:8686/acces?

Comment: Your last error means that struts-bridge is not "translating" the action you wrote as "portlet-action"... Did you read following page? http://portals.apache.org/bridges/bridges-struts/features.html

Comment: Hi Cira, I've tried many configuration but unfortunately i'm have always problems to execute my struts actions. no i don't have anye error in log but  the url generated display a blanck. can i send you my config files to see what's wrong in my config.Thank's in advance

Comment: The better idea is to create a new "Hello Word" portlet project (I'm sure you can find many examples/tutorials on the web)... try to make it working, then compare configurations and taglibs... if you aren't still able to solve, I think it is better to share your sources (es. github) and to open a new question on StackOverflow... in this way someone, and not just me, can try to help you... (because, I'm sure nobody else is reading this conversation) ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to get current logged in user in Liferay.

1 ] `User currentUser = PortalUtil.getUser( request );`

2 ] `User currentUser = (User) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.USER);`

3 ]

```
ThemeDisplay td  = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY );
User currentUser = td.getUser();`
```

4 ]

```
LiferayFacesContext liferayFacesContext = LiferayFacesContext.getInstance();
User currentUser = liferayFacesContext.getUser();
```

Hope one of them may help you.

Comment: Thank you Bhavin for your answer, but my problem is that the request doesn't contain :WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY it returns null, i've tried all these ways. is there some configuration to allow my struts web module to access liferay context?

Comment: I think the request object you are talking about is an instance of ActionRequest instead of an instance of HttpServletRequest

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the taglib directives You can get the user object in Liferay by doing the following in your jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="portlet" uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="theme" %>
<theme:defineObjects/> <%-- Gives you the user object. --%>
<%= user.getLogin() %>
```

See https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs-all/com/liferay/portal/model/User.html